# I have to "source ~/.zshrc" everytime I open a new terminal only in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, zshrc

Currently have to manually write `source ./zshrc` to get my zsh plugins to work within the vscode terminal window, however I dont have this issue if I open a zsh shell outside of vscode. I am using Debian on wsl2.
In terminal I get proper syntax example (due to a plugin)

[image]

However in vscode I dont unless i run `source ./zshrc`

As seen here:

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://linuxpip.org/vscode-zsh/

Comment: No still no luck, it definitely opens zsh as my default shell but for some reason it doesnt run my .zshrc profile ;(

Comment: Where is .zshrc located? `ls -l ~/.zshrc`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 leonardpat leonardpat 254 Jan 16 09:38 /home/leonardpat/.zshrc

Comment: Did you verify that you **indeed** have a zsh shell loaded? A quick test is to type just a closing parenthese in the shell. If it is zsh, it will respond with _**zsh**: parse error near ')'_. If you do see the word _zsh_, verify next that you don't have accidentally the variable `ZDOTDIR` set in your shell, and (now it's getting paranoid) that the value of the variable `$-` contains a lower-case `i`.

Comment: Yeah checked everything all came back as expected, definitely running zsh